# i want to know about hql join query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i want to fire query like this

```
select c,f,fs,s 
from com.bean.CourseBean c,com.bean.FacultyBean f,
     com.bean.Faculty_SubjectBean fs,com.bean.SubjectBean s 
where f.facultyID=fs.facultyID AND s.subjectid=fs.subjectid 
  AND c.courseid=f.courseid AND collegeid=1
```

how i can fire this query.?

please help with this

Comment: i want to fire this query using hibernate...this query will return one list. right? 
i want to know that in what type of list i should store result of this query..

Comment: already got answer thanks for the help